# Laptop shuts down instead of going to sleep when lid closed

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, sleep-wake

EDIT: Updating to Catalina 10.15.6 seems to have resolved the issue, at least so far.  Only had it installed for one evening so I'm not 100% ready to say the issues are resolved

---

I have a Macbook Pro 16 inch with Catalina installed.  It's recently started exhibiting the following behaviour when I try to put it to sleep:

- When running on battery or standalone AC it sleeps as normal when the lid is closed or when I select sleep from the menu
- When connected to an OWC dock it sleeps only if the lid is open when I select sleep from the menu
- When I'm connected to the dock with the lid closed the computer shuts down instead of going to sleep when I select sleep from the menu
- If I put the computer to sleep when it's docked and then close the lid, it won't wake up until I open the lid

Has anyone else encountered this?  How do you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have been some kind of issue in OSX 10.15.5.  Upgrading to 10.15.6 appears to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which OWC dock model that you have there could be a firmware update; I see one on this webpage that specifically mentions "sleep"- [enter link description here](https://www.owcdigital.com/search/results?search=dock%20firmware) I would also look into their app [Dock Ejector](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/dock-ejector). That might help with the issue. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It's an OWC Thunderbolt 3 dock, for which I couldn't find any firmware updates.  As for the ejector, I was under the impression that it simply ejected all the media that might be connected via the dock?

Comment: Maybe there's some weird communication going on between the dock and your MacBook that the app could solve (or is creating if you already have it installed). Might be worth a shot. I've never encountered this issue so I'm just thinking of how I might go about troubleshoonintg it.

Comment: The thing is it worked fine at first with earlier versions of Catalina, I think a Catalina update might have borked it in some way.  It also works fine when I've got my work-provided Macbook (running Sierra) hooked up to the dock instead of my personal Macbook.

Comment: Ah... yeah, it's gotta be Catalina then. Figure it had to be a software issue; I just assumed it might be a firmware issue with the dock itself. Dang... sorry we couldn't find an immediate solution. Hopefully Big Sure addresses the issue in the Fall.